# Error: A value of type 'Future<List<Publicfile>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Publicfile>'

Tags: function, flutter, dart, future

Here Publicfile is a user define class

```
List<Publicfile> publicFilesList = await Storage().listPublicFiles();
```

this command is use to recieve the list of files which is created by Storage Class and even though the listPublicFiles() is a ayns function and if I'm using the await keyword correctly,it is showing this error Error: A value of type 'Future<List>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'
And the Code for the Storage().listPublicFiles() is

```
Future<List<Publicfile>> listPublicFiles() async {
List<Publicfile> pf = new List();
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
List<String> Token;
try {
  var myUrl = await publicRefMetadata.getDownloadURL();
  print(myUrl);
  var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(myUrl.toString()));
  var response = await request.close();
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    Token = utf8.decode(bytes).split("\n");
    print(Token);
  }
} catch (ex) {
  print(ex);
}

}
```

}

Comment: Your function doesn't have return statement this might be problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: @AlperenEkin No, it has in the original code, but I didn't add here because this is not the complete function it has some more feature which I didn't add that is not relevant in this context. And Also other things are working fine.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I did that too but it is showing **Unexpected await** and **Future<List<Publicfiles>> cannot assign to List<Publicfiles>**

Comment: Your function is support to return something. But I don't see anything being returned. Why?